# same data structure mechanics with varying data type fields (C)

Tags: c, templates, data-structures, types

Suppose I want to implement a stack in C, with some various peculiarities, like deciding how to reallocate when it expands in a certain way, and so on. So something like

```
typedef struct stack_int {
    unsigned length;
    unsigned allocated_length;
    int *data_pointer;
} stack_int;

extern int stack_int_pop(stack *l);
```

and so on. But in my program, I would like to reuse it where `int` above gets replaced by, say, 5 data structures of my own (some structs which I use). In all cases I want the details to be the same.

**Question**: What is the "correct", or "idiomatic C", way to do that?

I can think of various roundabouts, like making a generic stack, with a field `element_size`, but then the interface when popping and appending would be necessarily ugly and also not optimized, as far as I can see. I also found a roundabout which is replacing the above by

```
#define CONCAT_PRE(X, Y) X ## _ ## Y
#define CONCAT(X, Y) CONCAT_PRE(X, Y)
#define STACK_TYPE CONCAT(stack, STACK_ELEMENT_TYPE)

typedef struct STACK_TYPE {
    unsigned length;
    unsigned allocated_length;
    STACK_ELEMENT_TYPE *data_pointer;
} STACK_TYPE;

STACK_ELEMENT_TYPE CONCAT(STACK_TYPE, pop)(stack *l) {
...
}
```

and then including it several times:

```
#define STACK_ELEMENT_TYPE int
#include "stack.c"
#define STACK_ELEMENT_TYPE my_struct
#include "stack.c"
```

but this does not seem like a "idiomatic C" way, is very confusing to someone who will read it, prevents a single header file, and so on and so on...

Comment: How about using a generic `void *` pointer, together with an `element_size`? And instead of the pop function returning the value, pass a pointer to the value to the function as an argument, and use `memcpy` to copy the value to it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That is what I thought, but first this creates an ugly interface, in the sense that the user needs to always remember how to do it (the pop and append) in a strange way, and second, the call to memcpy seems quite wasteful to me, for just a few bytes at a time, isn't it? Seems a "hack"...

Comment: Then how about a simple generic "stack" structure, without the pointer to the data, but with pointers to functions. Then a set of structures that "inherit" from the base stack structure (it includes the base stack structure as the first member) for each specific type? Then the base interface calls the correct functions using the function pointers. Still need to pass pointers to values instead of returning values.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought about this. Maybe it is not too bad. So you mean re-implementing pop and append (in a deterministic copy-paste way) for each new field type?

Comment: Or possibly, using multiple structure with "inheritance" and [generic selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic)?

Comment: The reimplementation of the push and pop functions could be done using macros, but (IMO) a nicer way than having to define a `STACK_ELEMENT_TYPE` macro.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about this _Generic thing, will look at it...

Comment: Either way, you're not getting out of having quite a lot of code duplication. But then again, macros can help you with that.

Comment: This is more or less how vectors/stacks are implemented in [STC](https://github.com/stclib/STC/blob/master/docs/cvec_api.md). And no, this is not idiomatic because type-generic containers are not idiomatic in C.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I’m not entirely sure what the "most idiomatic" thing would be to do here, but it’s for sure not including the same header multiple times, please refrain from doing that, as it could create dependency loops, and if you’re using a better IDE than Editor.exe, you should already have an include guard in your .h file anyway.

For your problem however, I’d argue to use a
**(void *)** and a type field consisting of an unsigned char, at least that is how Java classifies it’s data structures. Additionally, you just define numbers that correlate to your own structures.

This method is especially helpful of course, when you already have pointers to your structs you mentioned.

If you’re not keen on using that kind of (admittedly a bit awkward) method, you are always welcome to create multiple stacks that exist concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, using `void*` for passing pointers around, and `unsigned char *` for doing address calculations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
struct VoidStack {
    unsigned used_length;
    unsigned allocated_length;
    unsigned elem_bytes;
    void *data;
};
 
void *stack_pop(struct VoidStack *s) {
    return (unsigned char *)s->data + (--s->used_length * s->elem_bytes);
}
 
void stack_push(struct VoidStack *s, void *src) {
    if (s->used_length == s->allocated_length) {
        // grow data and update allocated_length
    }
    memcpy((unsigned char *)s->data + (s->used_length++ * s->elem_bytes),
          src, s->elem_bytes);
}
 
// etc
 
int main(void) {
    struct VoidStack intStack;
    intStack.used_length = 0;
    intStack.allocated_length = 4;
    intStack.elem_bytes = sizeof (int);
    intStack.data = malloc(4 * intStack.elem_bytes);
    int foo = 42, bar = -1, baz = 0, quux = 2023;
    stack_push(&intStack, &foo);
    stack_push(&intStack, &bar);
    stack_push(&intStack, &baz);
    stack_push(&intStack, &quux);
    printf("unstack: %d", *(int*)stack_pop(&intStack));
    printf(" %d", *(int*)stack_pop(&intStack));
    printf(" %d", *(int*)stack_pop(&intStack));
    printf(" %d\n", *(int*)stack_pop(&intStack));
    free(intStack.data);
    return 0;
}
```

See code running on https://ideone.com/4HRYn5 (using `xx` rather than `intStack`, sorry)

Comment: Thanks, but isn't the use of memcpy here a bit disappointing (I am not sure, I am a novice)? it is a function call where you could use equality, it is a (very soft, but still) dependency...

Comment: To use assignment you would have to do a loop: `for (size_t k = 0; k < elem_bytes; k++) (unsigned char *)dst + k = (unsigned char *)src + k;`. I find `memcpy()` easier on the eyes (and it may even be faster because it can use implementation tricks). Depending on inclusion of the `<string.h>` header (otherwise `memcpy()` is already part of the Standard Library) is a very small price to pay.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a classic way to implement a generic stack mechanism and instantiate the structures and methods using macros. It is easy to extend to other scalar or non-scalar types and allows for implementation variations for cases where the macro generated code is inadequate.

Declarations in **stack.h**:

```c
#define DEFINE_STACK_TYPE(T, name)  \
typedef struct name {   \
    int pos;            \
    int size;           \
    T *data;            \
} name

DEFINE_STACK_TYPE(int, stack_int);
DEFINE_STACK_TYPE(double, stack_double);
DEFINE_STACK_TYPE(char *, stack_string);

/* pop an element from the stack, return 0 if stack is empty */
extern int stack_int_pop(stack_int *s);
extern double stack_double_pop(stack_double *s);
extern char *stack_string_pop(stack_string *s);

/* push an element on the stack, return the index or -1 if allocation failed */
extern int stack_int_push(stack_int *s, int val);
extern int stack_double_push(stack_double *s, double val);
extern int stack_string_push(stack_string *s, char *val);

#if defined __STDC_VERSION__ && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L
/* generic interface using _Generic() */
#define stack_push(s, val)  _Generic(s,         \
    stack_int *:    stack_int_push(s, val),     \
    stack_double *: stack_double_push(s, val),  \
    stack_string *: stack_string_push(s, val),  \
)
#define stack_pop(s)  _Generic(s,           \
    stack_int *:    stack_int_pop(s),       \
    stack_double *: stack_double_pop(s),    \
    stack_string *: stack_string_pop(s),    \
)
#endif
```

Definitions in **stack.c**:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"

#define DEFINE_STACK_POP(T, stype, fname)       \
T fname(stype *s) {                             \
    return s->pos > 0 ? s->data[--s->pos] : 0;  \
}

#define DEFINE_STACK_PUSH(T, stype, fname)              \
int fname(stype *s, T val) {                            \
    T *data = s->data;                                  \
    while (s->pos >= s->size) {                         \
        int size = s->size + (s->size >> 1) + 32;       \
        data = realloc(data, sizeof(T) * size);         \
        if (data == NULL)                               \
            return -1;                                  \
        s->data = data;                                 \
        s->size = size;                                 \
    }                                                   \
    s->data[s->pos] = val;                              \
    return s->pos++;                                    \
}

DEFINE_STACK_POP(int, stack_int, stack_int_pop)
DEFINE_STACK_POP(double, stack_double, stack_double_pop)
DEFINE_STACK_POP(char *, stack_string, stack_string_pop)

DEFINE_STACK_PUSH(int, stack_int, stack_int_pop)
DEFINE_STACK_PUSH(double, stack_double, stack_double_pop)
DEFINE_STACK_PUSH(char *, stack_string, stack_string_pop)
```

It is possible to use macros to simulate parameterized types and replace the `DEFINE_STACK_TYPE` declarations with:

```
#define stack(T) \
struct {         \
    int pos;     \
    int size;    \
    T *data;     \
}

typedef stack(int) stack_int;
typedef stack(double) stack_double;
typedef stack(char *) stack_string;
```

Note however that `stack(int)` should only be used to define types with `typedef` as it would define a different type if used in multiple contexts, such as `int stack_int_pop(stack(int) *s);`